# Ios simulator - after keyboard comes up, how do I make it go away and what is the involved ux pattern?

Tags: ios, ios5

I have a small form that I want to have people fill out on the iPhone.  The form screenshot is attached.

[image]

Below the text area there is a submit button. How do I make the keyboard go away so that I can press the submit button?

Also, for users it is very confusing, especially if there is more things below the form...they might never even find those things there.

What is the typical ui/ux pattern for making such actions clear? And how do I put down the keyboard so I can press the submit button that the keyboard is covering?

Thank you!!

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply call `[textView resignFirstResponder]` when the user taps anywhere in the parent view outside the textView. You need to call that in `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`.  Or put your view in a UIScrollView and have it scroll up when the user starts typing (check Omar's link). THis way you can show the information below the textView.